# Storing the replies to an SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

Is there a way to store the replies of the SMS are sent from MobileConnect?

For example, I send an SMS offering a new product, and someone answer 'Hello, I would like to get more information'.

It is not about the use of keywords, it is just to store the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [info capture](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_info_capture.htm&type=5) SMS message template in mobile connect to prompt the user for input and then capture their response.

You can also add some scripting to your unrecognized command keyword in Mobile Connect that can return each word in the response as a keyword and then constructs it into a complete response and logs it (w/ their mobile number) to a data extension.

If you have any choice (i.e. not deploying this from a journey), then I'd recommend option 1.

Comment: I see the option of the info capture SMS, but what I would like to achieve is just to store the replies, it doesn't matter the content and it is not based in request an input from the customer.

Comment: You are going to have to create your own solution for this if you want it to be flexible. If the user texts your shortcode with a command/keyword (like the above response) that hasn't been set up, then you want to run a script for unrecognized commands that captures all the nouns/keywords (i.e. anything separated by a space) they input  and then concatenates them into a single string that you insert into a DE w/ their phone number and date. You're going to get some bad entries (accidental user input), but it's the only way I know of to do what you are asking.